# Convert Dates pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert dates in the format '31-Aug-91' into '31-08-1991' using pandas datetime.

I've tried `pd.to_datetime(df['INCIDENT_DATE'], format = '%d-%m-%y').dt.date`

But, I get the error ValueError: time data '31-Aug-91' does not match format '%d-%m-%y' (match)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `%b` for match first 3 letters of month names:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['INCIDENT_DATE'], format = '%d-%b-%y').dt.date
```

If need format `DD-MM-YYYY`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['INCIDENT_DATE'], format = '%d-%b-%y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```